# Regular Expressions to rename XML file contents in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I've searched through quite a few posts on here regarding Notepad++ regular expressions.  Here's what I'm trying to do.

Search for

```
<FolderName>1234: Client Name</FolderName>
```

Replace with

```
<FolderName>[1234] Client Name</FolderName>
```

The reason I'm not going line by line, which would be easier if there were a dozen or so folders, is because there are literally hundreds of "client folders" in this XML file.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated, and if there's already a post that goes over something like this, then I apologize for the double post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for anyone else running into a similar issue:

Search For:

```
(\<FolderName>)([0-9]+):(.*)(<)
```

Replace With:

```
\1[\2]\3<
```